# Running an Eclipse plugin/update mirror

Tags: eclipse, plugins, equinox, mirror, p2

I'm trying to run a full Eclipse mirror for all the plugins / updates our development team might want or need. This is because our network is impeded by a WebSense proxy filter, which very often blocks plugins from downloading.

This has been exceptionally frustrating for all the devs concerned.

I finally got approval to run an Eclipse mirror on a dedicated server, which has unfettered access to the internet, and which all internal machines can access.

I've done a lot of reading up and learning about the Equinox P2 update mechanism, and about update site publishing.

I selected a test plugin to act as a touchstone, to see if it all works. It appears to, except for one thing:
The plugin itself has dependencies, which Eclipse then tries to get from the internet, and I cannot find anyway to override this so that it comes back to our own mirror instead.

How can I force Eclipse to always use our mirror, or how can I publish / chain dependencies so that Eclipse gets them from the mirror?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure 100% understanding your question.

I think you can add your mirror server as a repository when installing plug-ins from Eclipse's wizard. And disable all the built-in servers that have problem to be accessed in your Intranet.

If you don't modify it on GUI, you can modify the prefs files of p2.

```
<your eclipse>/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/.settings/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.prefs
<your eclipse>/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/.settings/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.prefs
```